# Weighted average

Tags: python, python-3.x

the following code receives from user some grades on coursers that he took in previous semester and their weights. when user is done he will type "done" instead the grade.
I need to complete a code that compute weighted average and store it in variable res rounded to hundredths.

`weighted average = sum(grade*points)/sum(points)`

here is what I tried so far:

```
    grade = input("enter your grade: ")
    points = input("enter the points: ")
    #innitialise the variables before while loop:
    
sum_grade = 0
    sum_points = 0

    #write a while loop that terminates when the user enters "done" to grade variable

    #calculate the grade to variable res in this format XX.XX

    while grade != "done":
        sum_grade += int(grade)
        sum_points += int(points)
        grade = input("enter your grade: ")
        points = input("enter the points: ")
        continue
        else:
        break
        
    res = sum_grade*sum_points / sum_points

    res ="%.2f"%float
```

Thank you in advanced :-)

Comment: You need to go back and read on how [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) is calculated. Check the formula provided in the assignment again

Answer (score 2):

You have the right pieces. You just need to put them in the right order.

Try this code:

```
sum_grade = 0
sum_points = 0
while True:
    grade = input("enter your grade: ")
    if grade == "done": break  # done
    points = int(input("enter the points: "))
    grade = int(grade)
    sum_grade += grade * points
    sum_points += points
    
res = sum_grade / sum_points

res ="%.2f"%res

print(res)
```

Output

```
enter your grade: 10
enter the points: 10
enter your grade: 50
enter the points: 1
enter your grade: done
13.64
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `cnt`? and given that you `break` out of the loop - why not just use `while True:` and remove the need to initialize `grade` in the first place and use it in the while condition?

Comment: Loop updated. The `cnt` is the grade count needed for the final calculation.

Comment: it's weighted average, In the denominator it should be the sum of weights (points) as specified also in the assignment `weighted average = sum(grade*points)/sum(points)`

Comment: Yep - my logic was reversed. Answer updated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Numpy` as following :

```py
import numpy as np

np.average(sum_grade, axis=1, weights=sum_points)
```

or by modfying your code as follow :

```py
sum_grade += int(grade*points)
```

and

```py
res = sum_grade / sum_points
```

Comment: Clearly this homework assignment does not imply using `numpy`